# jQuery Find Nearest Checkbox & Check on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap list based on this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/checked-list-group

as per suggestions from the comments I have added this line to find and check the nearest checkbox.

```
 $checkboxinput = $(this).children('input')
```

and this line should check the hidden checkbox:

```
$checkboxinput.prop('checked', true);
```

For some reason, the first line will not find the checkbox. I hae tried other ways to find the checkbox with no luck.

Here is my codepen I have been working on http://codepen.io/jancouver/pen/MyovJr

Comment: how about `$checkboxinput = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checkbox')`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, that is not working. I think it must be `$(this)...` as there is a check box for every <li>

Comment: so why don't just use a selector like this: `$('li > input')`

Comment: I have it all figured out. Based on your suggestion I have changed the `$checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" class="hidden"/>')` to `$checkbox = $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]:checkbox'),` adn added the hidden field manually.  Thanks for the help!